# Blaze Templating - Attribute with no value

Tags: haskell, blaze-html

Using Blaze, how can I write an attribute with no value? As in an attribute that's just one string, with no `=`.

For example, I want to add a YouTube embed in Blaze, but I don't know how to add the `allowfullscreen` part. The blaze-from-html tool just errors out and tells me that it's illegal in HTML5, and I'm not sure how to do it from the documentation. Here's how the HTML should look:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/T4r91mc8pbo" 
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

I've tried creating a custom element like

```
allowfullscreen :: AttributeValue -> Attribute
allowfullscreen = attribute "allowfullscreen" " allowfullscreen"
```

but it appends the equal sign anyway - `allowfullscreen"="` and full screen is disallowed.

I'm using blaze-html 0.8.1.1 and blaze-markup 0.7.0.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### Boolean attributes ([HTML5 spec](http://w3c.github.io/html/infrastructure.html#sec-boolean-attributes))
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute’s canonical name, with no leading or trailing white space.
>
> #### Examples
>
> ```
> <label><input type=checkbox checked name=cheese disabled> Cheese</label>
> <label><input type=checkbox checked=checked name=cheese disabled=disabled> Cheese</label>
> <label><input type='checkbox' checked name=cheese disabled=""> Cheese</label>
> ```

See also [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2).

There is a [Github issue for blaze-html](https://github.com/jaspervdj/blaze-html/issues/80) about that.

So `allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"` should work.